# Get to list item which called by symbols or marked with $ sign

Tags: python

I use jsondiff.

I have next dict:
`<class 'dict'>: {'id': 1111, delete: ['longcode']}`

[image]

`delete` is not symbolic. When I try to get it by name, I have KeyError exception. But it presence. Idea is by using jsondiff get difference between json objects. And want to remove or separate `delete` list from dict

Comment: Show the JSON..

Comment: Please be more clear and provide the code you are using. From what I understand, the delete must be a string so try with key "delete" instead of delete unless its a variable

Comment: It is a return result of jsondiff lib

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. `diff` method allows to dump data. For this need to specify Boolean attribute `dump=True`

`diff(json1, json2, dump=True)`